# SQLITE timestamp in java , returning the same date everytime

Tags: java, sqlite, timestamp

I have a little problem working with sqlite. Whenever i try to get the timestamp from the sqlite table, it returns a same date all the time.
Here is my code:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM chat_cache");
Timestamp ts = resultSet.getTimestamp("timestamp");
System.out.println(ts);
```

Output:`1970-01-01 05:30:00.0`

But when i change my code to :

```
String ts = resultSet.getString("timestamp");
```

I get the correct timestamp. `2012-11-08 08:05:54`
Why is it so? why is sqlite not supporting resultSet.getTimestamp("timestamp") ??

Answer (score 0):

Your JDBC driver (whichever one you're using) does not support timestamps in string format.

Look into its documentation to see what timestamp format you have to use (it appears it wants Unix timestamps, which are seconds since 1970).

Alternatively, read and parse the strings in your application.